# How to generate Google Ads tag via Google API?

Tags: google-api, ads, google-ads-api, gtag.js

I need to generate it via google API:

```
<!-- Global Site Tag (gtag.js) - Google AdWords: GOOGLE_CONVERSION_ID -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-GOOGLE_CONVERSION_ID"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments)};
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'AW-GOOGLE_CONVERSION_ID');
</script>
```

not via https://adwords.google.com web interface,
but via something like https://api.adwords.google.com

so I do some POST/PUT Request to this (https://api.adwords.google.com) URL

and get in response AW-GOOGLE_CONVERSION_ID or full script

Answer (score 0):

UPD: Here is a link with example 
https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/samples/php/remarketing